# How can I optimize the intersections between lists with two elements and generate a list of lists without duplicates in python?

Tags: python, list, optimization, intersection

I need help with my loop. In my script I have two huge lists (~87.000 integers each) taken from an input file.

Check this example with a few numbers:

We have two lists:

`nga = [1, 3, 5, 34, 12]`

`ngb = [3, 4, 6,  6,  5]`

The order of these two lists matters because each position is related with the same position in the other list, so `1` in `nga` is related with `3` in `ngb`, `3` with `4`, etc...

So what I want is this output:

`listoflists = [[1, 3, 4], [5, 6, 12, 34]]`

What I have so far is this loop:

```
listoflists = []

for p in range(0, len(nga)):
    z = [nga[p], ngb[p]]
    for a, b in zip(nga, ngb):
        if a in z:
            z.append(b)
        else:
            pass
        if b in z:
            z.append(a)
        else:
            pass
    listoflists.append(z)
```

The problem appears when I used the whole lists, because it crashed and give me a Segmentation fault error. So, what can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using python 2 or python 3?

Comment: What is the procedure going from `nga = [1, 3, 5, 34, 12]` and `ngb = [3, 4, 6, 6, 5]` to `listoflists = [[1, 3, 4], [5, 6, 12, 34]]`?

Comment: with your input I get `[[1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3], [3, 4, 1, 4, 3], [5, 6, 6, 5, 34, 12], [34, 6, 5, 6, 34, 12], [12, 5, 6, 5, 34, 5, 12]]`

Comment: Algorithmically, it looks atrocious. There should be no need to zip inside a loop that is already iterating on the same couples. Whatever you are trying to do, think about how you can do it better by taking advantage of the fact that your lists are ordered.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre python 3 and then I need to unify and remove the duplicates so I can get listoflists

Comment: @JulienD ooh I didn't know that :( With smaller lists my script works like a charm, this is the part of it that take the greatest time and it crashes, so maybe it's a better option do a list of paired elements before this step and with a smaller loop or something more simple? I don't know...

Comment: Please give some further details about the criteria creating the desired output. I still did not get the point...

Comment: @albert this output: `[[1, 3, 3, 1, 4, 3], [3, 4, 1, 4, 3], [5, 6, 6, 5, 34, 12], [34, 6, 5, 6, 34, 12], [12, 5, 6, 5, 34, 5, 12]]` will do it as well, but I need a faster and better way to do it with my big lists

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this beautiful function:

```
net = []
for a, b in zip(nga, ngb):
    net.append([a, b])

def nets_super_gen(net):
    not_con = list(net)
    netn = list(not_con[0])
    not_con.remove(not_con[0])
    new_net = []
    while len(netn) != len(new_net):
        new_net = list(netn)
        for z in net:
            if z[0] in netn and z[1] not in netn:
                netn.append(z[1])
                not_con.remove(z)
            elif z[0] not in netn and z[1] in netn:
                netn.append(z[0])
                not_con.remove(z)
            try:
                if z[0] in netn and z[1] in netn:
                    not_con.remove(z)
            except ValueError:
                pass
    return(netn, not_con)

list_of_lists, not_con = nets_super_gen(net)
```